# Remove all java keywords from a file

Tags: java, filereader, keyword

I am going through a project where I need to remove all java keywords from a java file. First I create a **keyword.java** file and store all java keywords into this file.Like **abstract continue for new switch assert default goto package** etc which I store keyword.java file. I have another file named newFile.java and  I read all data from **newFile.java** as a String. I have to remove all java keywords from  newFile.java file. As far I tried:

```
   public void processFile() throws IOException {
    String data = "";
    data = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("H:\\java\\Clone\\newFile.java"))).trim();
    String rmvPunctuation = removePunctuation(data);
    String newLineRemove = rmvPunctuation.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "");
    String spaceRemove = newLineRemove.replaceAll("( ){2,}", " ");     
    removeKeyword(spaceRemove);}


 public void removeKeyword(String fileAsString) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    ArrayList<String> keyWordList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> methodContentList = new ArrayList<>();
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("H:\\java\\keyword.java");
    byte[] b = new byte[fis.available()];
    fis.read(b);
    String[] keyword = new String(b).trim().split(" ");
    String newString = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < keyword.length; i++) {
        keyWordList.add(keyword[i].trim());

    }
    String[] p = fileAsString.split(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < p.length; i++) {
        if (!(keyWordList.contains(p[i].trim()))) {
            newString = newString + p[i] + " ";
        }
    }
    System.out.println("" + newString);
}
```

But I could not found my desired output. All the java keywords are not removed from newFile.java file. I think StackOverflow community help me to solve this. I am also a beginner.

I also tried:

```
  public void removeKeyword(String fileAsString) throws IOException {
    String keyWord = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("H:\\java\\keyword.java"))).trim();
    String text = fileAsString.trim();
    ArrayList<String> wordList = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<String> keyWordList = new ArrayList<>();
    wordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(text.split(" ")));
    keyWordList.addAll(Arrays.asList(keyWord.split(" ")));    
     wordList.removeAll(keyWordList);
    System.out.println("" + wordList.toString());

}
```

Comment: Why are the keywords stored in a file called keyword.java? Just store the keywords in a hardcoded List instead. And what is a keyword exactly? class, public, int, do, while, for, ...?

Comment: Did you try stepping through your code using the debugger?

Comment: @luk2302 yes that is class,public etc. Can you help me by giving me the exact solution using a hardcoded list?

Comment: What is the expected output?  this code doesn't change newFile.java - it writes  something to System.out (and makes it 1 big line if I understand it correctly)...

Comment: @MrR some keywords remove form file like public ,new..but doesnot remove all keyword.

Comment: If you don't have a debugger - why not confirm that you have all the keywords loaded `System.err.println("Nof Keywords" + keyWordList.size());` - if that's not matching what you expect - then look what needs fixing there.  Perhaps also think about making your keywordList a keywordSet .. `Set<String> keywords = new HashSet<String>();` should make the lookups quicker (it doesn't have to look at the whole list to confirm not used - just has to look at 1 element).

Comment: Then what things aren't being found - perhaps it's because they don't have a space after them??

Comment: @MrR thanks . I did not notice the space.In keyword.java file I did not put space in between them.Now it works .